# eclipse not running on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

When I start eclipse I just get this small eclipse windows [image]

after this the program never starts . Last time I had this same problem . I though a reinstall would solve it. Has anybody faced similar problem ?

Comment: Which version of eclipse and JDK you are using ?

Comment: Ecilpse Juno(4.2) and Java 1.6

Comment: can you clean the workspace and try again..

Comment: I deleted the workspace . Now it seems to be running . But why does this happen so often ? I mean last time also I had to delete the workspace .

Comment: Sometimes .metadata use to get corrupt I don't know why. You can import your previous project to your new workspace. See [restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/)